# Automated Apache STORM deployment

Tags: virtual-machine, ubuntu-12.04, apache-storm

Is there an easy way to deploy Apache storm on a local machine (Ubuntu 12.4 LTS vm) for evaluation purposes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer following links for Apache storm deployment on one machine :

https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki/Setting-up-development-environment

http://10jumps.com/blog/storm-installation-single-machine

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy a pseudo-distributed cluster with Docker: 
https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/fhuz/docker-storm/

Answer (score 1):

I can't recommend [wirbelsturm](https://github.com/miguno/wirbelsturm) high enough.

We used it to kickstart our production like dev environment.

Answer (score 0):

Running Apache Storm on a local machine for testing purposes is ridiculously easy. Checkout [Storm Local Mode](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki/Local-mode).

Answer (score 0):

If you use the below code, the topology is submited to the cluster through active nimbus node.

```
StormSubmitter.submitTopology("Topology_Name", conf, Topology_Object);
```

But if you use the below code, the topology is submited locally in the same machine. In this case, a new local cluster is created with nimbus, zookeepers and supervisors in the same machine.

```
LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
cluster.submitTopology("Topology_Name", conf, Topology_Object);
```